# Chrome - Disable cache for localhost only?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I'm using localhost for development; and I'm directly including jquery from CDN.

It seems that pressing the "Ctrl + R" would force the page to reload, including re-downloading the jquery from CDN.

I want to ask if it's possible that.. when I refresh, I keep the cache of the jquery from CDN, but clear the cache of my localhost?

NOTE: I know that one thing I can do is to host jquery file locally; I'm just asking to see if there's a way to bypass that.

Comment: Use shift+F5 to refresh the page, it forces to clear cache.. If doesn't work try to press a few times.

Comment: How about keeping the cache from remote server..?

Comment: i think he wants to KEEP it cached. Not cleared from cache. On really slow internet, waiting for CDN is annoying,but caching local files that you're working on is also annoying - so would be nice to have a mix. I've resorted to downloading the CDN file locally for now.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can certainly prevent all your file from hitting the cache, but this is an all-or-nothing setting. You can't decide which files get cleared from the cache and which files stay in the cache.

During development, since you are using Chrome, I'd recommend to enable the setting for "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)":

[image: Disable cache (while DevTools is open)]

If you are like me, cache will be disabled every time you have the DevTools panel opened.

Another thing you can do is to instruct your server to bypass cache altogether for all your resources. Since jQuery is coming from a CDN, this no-cache setting won't apply for it. To disable cache for resources you can include the following response header:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
```

Comment: For the current version of chrome "61", this feature moved to the developer tool. To activate it you have to go to: More Tools > Developer tools > Network "tab" then click on Disable cache. Note that this work only when the Developer tool is open.

Answer (score 50):

In the browser, use this to refresh the page: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

this will ignore the cache (whereas Ctrl+r will use the cache).

yw :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasted half an hour trying to clear the cache( I didn't want to clear my history)

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> on linux/windows or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> on Mac to open developer tools, then go to `network` tab, and click on `Disable cache`

Answer (score 6):

**Mac only:** You can also hold down the refresh button and a menu with three options pops up:

[image: Empty cache with Chrome]

Comment: tried this in latest Chrome/Edge and does not work (Windows)

Comment: THANK YOU. Nothing else I tried worked consistently.

Comment: you need to have the browser console open to see these options.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Apache you can disable cache on your server (localhost) by placing .htaccess file into your htdocs directory (or directory which you want to disable the cache for) with following content:

```
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1 (My fav)

I use this chrome extension. Note u will have to go into the extension options first and add the URL of the site you want to disable cache on.

Extension Link - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-cache/ogbfmfambmmhfdpfokohebghmcdbodbh

### Method 2

You can press Ctrl+Shift+R for a hard reload which will reload without cache.

Answer (score -3):

Or you can just open a Chrome tab in incognito mode **Ctrl + Shift + N**