# XAMPP Server does not load CSS files

Tags: php, css, xampp

Actually I'm working on a small projects with XAMPP server, Most of the times I have this crazy problem,When I change anything in my CSS file it doesn't any effect but when I restart my XAMPP apache server several times it works fine. anyone knows how I can fix this problem permanently?

Comment: You need to learn about how browsers are working. Here you will have to check requests headers to understand what happened (it'll be pretty self explanatory)

Answer (score 33):

Are you using browser caching?

Maybe just try a hard refresh <kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd>

Sorry if this is obvious and you have already tried it!

Comment: So was I so you get 2 UV. When you get to 50 reps, remember to comment

Comment: Tnx buddy, It really worked for me and actually I didn't know about this simple but important thing.

Comment: Thanks, It works..

Comment: That's a great solution to understand that caching is actually a great solution.
From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751767/chrome-disable-cache-for-localhost-only it's not possible to disable caching just for localhost, but you can overall disable it.

Comment: Worked like a charm! :)

Comment: It helped, thank you! But I don't understand why... I mean what has cache got to do with anything? Can anybody please answer me?

Comment: @JustLearn the cache in this instance is the browser cache. Chrome/Firefox/etc - they all keep a cache of loaded files so that they can make less network requests but often, when the file has changed they don't load the new version so you don't get your changes

Answer (score 1):

The xampp cannot be the problem, You can verify it by opening the .html file directly in the browser. The possible problem could be you havent set the path for your css file correctly.

Refer
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

or try inline code for testing that your changes are seen properly.

If there is cache problem try open in incognito window

tricky way:
1) open your html file at local host on the browser.
2) now press Shift+ctrl+J to open the console.
3) now you'll find 'Source' option (right-side of console option) at the top of new window.
4) click 'source' option and then you''l find your folder having all the .html, .css, .js, .php files available at local host.
5) open the appropriate file (what you what to edit) and modify it.
6) press ctrl+S to save your modification.
    now you will see the changes.(according to your modification)

Comment: Tnx for answer.. Ben Lonsdale's answer worked perfect.