# Linking both CSS and Bootstrap in HTML file

Tags: html, css

I'm linking my .CSS file and Bootstrap 4.2.1 to my HTML file. The .CSS Isn't linking correctly. What is the correct way to link my stylesheet to an HTML file? Bootstrap works but not CSS.

I have tried changing the order of the links. I have also made sure my HTML and CSS files are in the same folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
```

Comment: Is your stylesheet in the right path?

Answer (score 1):

you wrote *stlye* instead of style? maybe it's just the mispelling
or you might need to specify the path for your css
something like this before your css file ~/filename.css

Comment: thank you for the spelling catch but that did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="stlye.css"/>` should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>`
You spelt style wrongly. Also make sure `style.css` is in the same folder/path as your `index.html` (or whichever `.html` page you are using), else be sure to specify the path like so: `/example/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the style file **exists** and you are importing your stylesheet with the **correct name and relative path**. That means use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>` if your css is in the same folder of your html file. Otherwise provide the correct route for your file. **For example** would be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/assets/style.css"/>`  if your css is inside app/assets folder.

Comment: I have my index.php and style.css in the same folder. What else can i try? Does it have something to do with xampp?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502863/xampp-server-does-not-load-css-files/41502889 maybe that would help