# Cookies are erased when opening dev tools on localhost

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, localhost

Anytime I have dev tools open on localhost my cookies are deleted and I am redirected to the login page on every page load which means I cannot use dev tools to debug or get insight into my site. I have localhost setup with a valid SSL cert (self-signed) and the site works normally until I open dev tools. How do I fix or disable this new "security" or setting in chrome?

Comment: I think this will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751767/chrome-disable-cache-for-localhost-only

Comment: @Oden thanks for reaching out, I tried it out just for fun but it didn't change anything. I don't know why disabling cache would help prevent cookies from being deleted anyways

Answer (score 0):

After lots of issues and trying out many different things I came across this post/answer

[When adding a Javascript library, Chrome complains about a missing source map, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205390/when-adding-a-javascript-library-chrome-complains-about-a-missing-source-map-w/63383126#63383126)

Turns out that when I opened Dev Tools it would request a CSS map and the request was being sent to a different firewall causing my application to require me to re-authenticate every time this resource was requested. Turning off the CSS source map option fixed the issue